# xaml: navigate external link in button click

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

my xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/fb.png" Text="like" Click="like"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

my c# code:

```
private void like(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/myprofile", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

But while run;

App breaks whenever i pressed the like button. Help me pleass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationService.Navigate`, on Windows Phone, is used to navigate to another XAML page not a remote URI. If you want to launch the WebBrowser, you can either have a `WebBrowser` control or use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
private void like(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbt.Uri = new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/myprofile", UriKind.Absolute);
    wbt.Show();
}
```

(The `UriKind` should be `Absolute` in this case).

Answer (score -2):

The Uri you are navigating to appears to be absolute and not relative.

Try changing to:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/myprofile", UriKind.Absolute));